# Mysql - Best way to store tags and search for an exact tag

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I am having problem with mysql to search for a tag properly.
Currently I am storing tags like this-

```
  id  |   name   |           tags
======+==========+============================
  1   | Pen      | pen, pencil, writings, edit
------+----------+----------------------------
  2   | Money    | currency, penny, dollar
------+----------+----------------------------
  3   | Car      | suspension, fast
------+----------+----------------------------
```

Currently I'm using this code to target **id 1** name **Pen** (Record 1)

```
SELECT * FROM ____ WHERE tags LIKE '%pen%'
```

But I am getting all these 3 record because-

- **pen**, **pen**cil, writings, edit
- currency, **pen**ny, dollar
- sus**pen**sion, fast

**I only want record 1, When I search for the keyword pen**

Comment: Please do not store comma separated data. Normalize it please.

Comment: You should normalize but https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set might be a temporary solution. (Also this isn't a PHP question, please limit tag usage to languages used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As was mentioned above, don't store all tags in single column, normalize it. For example, you should have entity's table (contains Pen, Car, etc), tags table (pen, pencil,penny, etc) and relation table which will contain ids from both tables in two columns within indexes.
2. In current schema you could change search criteria from:

   `LIKE '%pen%' to = 'pen' OR LIKE 'pen, %' OR LIKE '% pen, %' OR LIKE '% pen'`.

   But you know, it's ugly solution anyway....

Comment: [How to Fix the Comma Separated List of Doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html)

Comment: I like your solution bro! Thanks...